# Поиск точек в радиусе круга.Object Manager

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

вопрос, у меня несколько ObjectManager на карте, порядка 10, в каждом около 5-7 тыс точек. Не пойму, как реализовать поиск точек, входящих в радиус. На форуме читал что ОМ и geoQuery не совместимы, в примерах используется geoQuery и searchInside.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен на счёт эффективности такого метода, но можно попробовать использовать метод setFilter https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#method_detail__setFilter